# Weird result using group by

Tags: sorting, group-by

I help run a small radio station and we log stats in to a MySQL database.
I have started seeing weird results when using the following code to grab peaks for each entry logged in the stats table.

I have tried a few things in the code but not seen any change in results so far.

SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            stat_utc,
            stat_master_count,
            stat_master_track
        FROM
            stats_all_master
        ORDER BY
            stat_master_count DESC,
            stat_utc DESC
    ) AS my_table_tmp
GROUP BY
    stat_master_track
ORDER BY
    stat_master_count DESC,
    stat_utc DESC
LIMIT 5;

If I remove the GROUP BY stat_master_track I see results with higher stat_count.

With GROUP BY:

41    LIVE SHOW ~ Erebuss - Mixset Showcase Mix 2018 (29/12/18)
41    Mixset ~ Inna Rhythm Recordings - Mix 01 (2015)
39    LIVE SHOW ~ DJ Ransome - Mixset Showcase 2017
38    LIVE SHOW ~ Parts Unknown - PartsUnknown #007
37    LIVE SHOW ~ MrKrotos - Mixset Showcase 2018 Part 2 (2018-12-29)

Without GROUP BY I see records with higher count like:

51    LIVE SHOW ~ DnB_Bo - Mixset Showcase Mix 2018 Part 1 (29/12/18)
47    LIVE SHOW ~ Erebuss - Renegade sessions #0006 (UK)
46    LIVE SHOW ~ DnB_Bo - Mixset Showcase Mix 2018 Part 1 (29/12/18)

Comment: Could you give us a snapshot of  your data? It's hard to tell what each of these columns refer to.

Comment: Hi there, I have a shot of the table @ https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw4qh61mo36w8w9/table.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting the structure, I was more after a couple of individual rows of data - for example what is actually contained within the `stat_master_track` column?

Comment: Test data dump @ https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyp9wqdy3txvfu7/test%20data.sql?dl=0

Comment: Sorry just seen your comment, I have a test data dump above I just uploaded, took a few minutes to get that data together

Comment: The stat_master_track column contains the track name/show name/advert name etc...
As part of my trying to fix this iuuse I changed it from varchar to text to see if that had any change on sorting but it made no difference.